# Positivity of a matrix built on Pascal's triangle

Tags: matrices, binomial-coefficients, positive-definite, toeplitz-matrices

For an integer $n$, let $T_n$ be the $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ Toeplitz matrix built on the $2n$th row of Pascal's triangle, i.e., its $(i,j)$ entry equals $\binom{2n}{n+i-j}$. For example,
$$ T_2 =\begin{pmatrix} 6 & 4 & 1 \\ 4 & 6 & 4 \\ 1 & 4 & 6 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Numerical experiments indicate that $T_n$ is always positive definite. How to prove this claim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since
$$
2^{2n} \cos^{2n} t = \big(e^{it} + e^{-it}\big)^{2n} = \sum_{k=-n}^{n}{2n \choose n+k} e^{2tki},
$$
we have
$$
{2n \choose n+k} = \frac{2^{2n-1}}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-2tki}\cos^{2n}t\, dt. 
$$
Then, for any $z_0,\dots,z_n \in \mathbb C$,
$$
\sum_{k,l=0}^n {2n \choose n+k-l} z_k \overline{z_l} = \frac{2^{2n-1}}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sum_{k,l=0}^n e^{-2t(k-l)i}z_k \overline{z_l} \cos^{2n}t\, dt \\
= \frac{2^{2n-1}}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi\left|\sum_{k=0}^n e^{-2tki}z_k \right| ^2 \cos^{2n}t\, dt\ge 0.
$$
This proves that $T_n$ is positive definite.